# Why aren't <script> tags not working on this PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

When I try to enter

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("hello");
</script>
```

in the comment box on my PHP page I do not get an alert box. I see the script in my text file, not on the webpage. For some reason the `<script>` isn't executing. I have active scripting and javascript enabled on all my browsers.

```
My PHP code:

<?php //CFPcomments.php

include_once 'CFPheader.php';




if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $fp = fopen('comments.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['content'] . "<br />");
    fclose($fp);
}

echo nl2br(file_get_contents('comments.txt'));





echo <<<_END
<h3>Post comment</h3>
<form action='CFPcomments.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='content' rows ='3' cols='100'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' value='Post' />
</form>
_END;
?>
```

Strange. I got it to work, not sure why.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello");
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I type this in it seems to work

Anyone have any idea why???? Very confused.

Comment: Do you include jquery.js file ????

Comment: @AmolNavsupe Do you think `window.alert` is part of jQuery?

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
                        alert("window load occurred!");
                  });

Comment: echo <<<_END  <script type="text/javascript" >
 alert("hello");
</script>
<h3>Post comment</h3>
<form action='CFPcomments.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='content' rows ='3' cols='100'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' value='Post' />
</form>
_END;

Comment: or use $(document).ready(function() {
                        alert('test'); 
                  });

Comment: please include the content of `comments.txt` into the question

Comment: @winner where did you place your script in php file???

Comment: Its working, you need to keep script code either with HTML part of outside PHP tags.

Comment: jquery isn't being used here. Just vanilla javascript.

Comment: you... are aware that you don't need to echo, right? You just do `?> HTML CONTENT HERE <?php /* php content resumes here`...

Comment: @Scuzzy comments.txt is blank

Comment: @winner You may want to do some reading on `XSS` if you haven't already. Allowing comments to contain Javascript makes you immediately vulnerable to that kind of attack. Depending on the use case you may be okay with that.

Comment: I moved the HTML code out of the PHP code. Still doesn't not work

Comment: @Paulpro I'm testing some XSS, just for fun. That is the purpose of this site.

Comment: @winner can i suggest using `file_put_contents()` instead of the `fopen(__,'a')` just to simplify your code for now? the other possibility is file system write permission issues.

Comment: @winner Ah, a perfect use case haha :) Just wanted to give you a warning, in case you didn't know about XSS.

Comment: @Scuzzy The script will be written to the textfile, just won't execute on the web page.

Comment: @winner you wrote "_comments.txt is blank_" though? Instead of writing to disk, why not just `echo $_POST['content'];`?

Comment: @Scuzzy because I deleted the contents of it. After every failed attempt I delete the contents In the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned a variable to the content, then displayed the variable in the PHP code. Now it works.

```
<?php //CFPcomments.php

include_once 'CFPheader.php';


setcookie("username", $GLOBALS['user'], time()+3600);
setcookie("password", $GLOBALS['pass'], time()+3600);
if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $fp = fopen('comments.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['content'] . "<br />");
    fclose($fp);
}

$comment =  file_get_contents('comments.txt');





echo <<<_END
<h3>Post comment</h3>
'$comment'
<form action='CFPcomments.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='content' rows ='3' cols='100'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='submit' value='Post' />
</form>
_END;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

your `nl2br()` is most likely translating

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("hello");
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" ><br/>
alert("hello");<br/>
</script><br/>
```

and breaking the JavaScript code.

Comment: why do you think so, script tag is in nl2br()

Comment: _breaking_ is a harsh word, I would say enhancing it to a point where it no longer serves its original purpose

Comment: @c-link if the intention is to echo the `<script>` tag unmodified, then `nl2br()` will be modifying it.

Comment: What does your browsers source indicate?

Comment: Ah yes, it is adding the <br/> tags

Comment: I tried echo $_POST['content']; instead of nlbr2 and it writes: <script type="text/javascript" >
alert("hello");
</script><br /><script type="text/javascript" >
alert("hello");
</script><br />

Comment: So its doubling the script AND adding <br> tags when I use echo $_POST['content'];